# How to ignore must condition for specified terms in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way that we can ignore applying must condition in elastic search queries for specified fields

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
     "filter": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [
              {
                 "term": {
                    "user": "abc@xyz.com"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
}
```

In the above query i am trying to filter all the records based on the particular user.

Requirement is, in one term i.e field i want to return all the records irrespective of user.

Ex :

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
     "filter": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [
              {
                 "term": {
                    "user": "abc@xyz.com"
                 },
                 "term":{
                    "field":"events",
                    "size":0
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Currently i am handling it with 2 queries, But is there any chance of doing it in single query?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I didn't get your question buddy. Can you please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, if I understood well the question:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "user": "abc@xyz.com"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "field": "events"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "field": "events"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response with my bad explaination. I was looking for something like events is a field which gets filtered based on user. I filter so many fields using this user. But i am looking for to ignore one field i.e events. With filtering say for example : i am getting events as 10 records, but overall it is more than 20+ with different users. I just want to ignore applying the condition to this field. Hope you got it...? It may sound awkward, but situation is something like this with my requirement ;)

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I don't understand.